# Filter array of dates between two dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of dates. I am trying to remove dates that are not between two dates. But I get SOME dates that are even before the "from" date. What am I doing wrong?

```
$scope.filterUpcomingEvents = function() {

    $scope.arrayOfEventData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.tempArray));

    console.log($scope.tempArray, "arrayofeve");
    for (let d = 0; d < $scope.arrayOfEventData.length; d++) {
        debugger;
        console.log(d);
        console.log(new Date($scope.tempArray[d].event_date), "from", $scope.upcomingEventFrom);
        console.log(new Date($scope.tempArray[d].event_date) < $scope.upcomingEventFrom);
        console.log(new Date($scope.tempArray[d].event_date), "to", $scope.upcomingEventTo);
        console.log(new Date($scope.tempArray[d].event_date) > $scope.upcomingEventTo);
        console.log("---");
        if (new Date($scope.arrayOfEventData[d].event_date) < $scope.upcomingEventFrom || new Date($scope.arrayOfEventData[d].event_date) > $scope.upcomingEventTo) {
            $scope.arrayOfEventData.splice(d, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log($scope.arrayOfEventData, "after splice");
}
```

In the console, though I get true for some comparisons, it is not spliced. When I see the finaly array, it still has the value that's supposed to be spliced though it's true and enters `if`.

Array of dates:

```
0: {
        event_id: "49",
        event_name: "julyevent",
        event_date: "2018-07-13",
        event_time: "11:00AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
1: {
        event_id: "50",
        event_name: "up event1",
        event_date: "2018-06-22",
        event_time: "11:11AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
2: {
        event_id: "52",
        event_name: "twe",
        event_date: "2018-06-29",
        event_time: "11:11AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
3: {
        event_id: "55",
        event_name: "eve4",
        event_date: "2018-06-23",
        event_time: "10:22PM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
4: {
        event_id: "56",
        event_name: "eve5",
        event_date: "2018-06-25",
        event_time: "11:11AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
5: {
        event_id: "57",
        event_name: "eve6",
        event_date: "2018-06-28",
        event_time: "10:00AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
6: {
        event_id: "58",
        event_name: "eve7",
        event_date: "2018-06-28",
        event_time: "9:00AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
7: {
        event_id: "59",
        event_name: "eve8",
        event_date: "2018-07-12",
        event_time: "7:00AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
8: {
        event_id: "60",
        event_name: "eve9",
        event_date: "2018-06-19",
        event_time: "4:00AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
9: {
        event_id: "61",
        event_name: "eve10",
        event_date: "2018-06-20",
        event_time: "8:00PM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
10: {
        event_id: "62",
        event_name: "eve11",
        event_date: "2018-06-23",
        event_time: "3:00AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
11: {
        event_id: "63",
        event_name: "eve12",
        event_date: "2018-06-21",
        event_time: "10:22PM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
12: {
        event_id: "64",
        event_name: "eve13",
        event_date: "2018-06-24",
        event_time: "6:00AM",
        event_type_id: "2",
        …
    }
```

Comment: Post your `array of dates` also.

Comment: Could you please add `$scope.tempArray` to the question for us to play around with your logic?

Comment: Have a look at [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to make your life easier.

Comment: @VicJordan posted it. it's the same as `$scope.arrayOfEventData`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are splicing from the same array that loop incrementally then array modifies and items get shifted. Because of that, you might miss an iteration.

One thing you can do is looping backward using a while loop so that you are not looping the direction where u splice.

```
let i = $scope.arrayOfEventData.length;
while(i--){
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `Array.filter`:

```
 $scope.arrayOfEventData =  $scope.arrayOfEventData.filter((a)=>(new Date(a.event_date) >= $scope.upcomingEventFrom || new Date(a.event_date) <= $scope.upcomingEventTo )));
```

Comment: How will this change the result?

Comment: @Andreas It gives us the array of events between the given two times.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is, that when you remove some element, you still increment  *d* by using *d++*. If you want to keep you code, remove *d++* from the loop:

```
for (let d=0; d<...;      ) // no d++
...
  if ()
    splice(d, 0);
  else
    d++;
```

But if you use Array.filter, you avoid such problems.